# SWF Loader -> TypeError: Error #1009 (Null reference)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I've read the previous posts of SO and it seems that some people's had the same issue as me - but none came up with a solution that helped my problem :)

I've designed 3 games that are their own SWF file, and I'm trying to load them upon a keypress in a container-program, sort of :).

I'm getting the TypeError 1009 null reference on all my SWF files though :( and they run perfectly when I load them from Windows. I've tried loading a SWF made by someone else, and that did work. So maybe my way of designing flash games is a bit off?
Everything takes place in frame 1 - that's maybe something that's off.

My loader code is:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, reportKeysDown);

function loaderFunction(swfFile:String):void {
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
    loader.load(new URLRequest(swfFile));
}

function onComplete(e:Event):void {
    var movie:* = LoaderInfo(e.currentTarget).content;
    //Adding content to the stage
    stage.addChild(movie);
}


function reportKeysDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void 
{ 
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.NUMBER_1) {
        stage.removeChildren(1);
        loaderFunction("Card.swf");
    }
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.NUMBER_2){
        stage.removeChildren(1);
        loaderFunction("Puzzle.swf");
    }
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.NUMBER_3){
        stage.removeChildren(1);
        loaderFunction("BallGame.swf");
    }
}
```

And the error is

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.     at BallGame_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

(I get these for everyone of the SWF's)

I'm not sure how to debug those games I'm loading since there's nothing wrong when I play separately. 
Any ideas :)? Thanks!

Edit:
It started telling me which lines were acting up, and it seems to be the keyboard-listener, at least for one of the games. I'm reading keyboard into much like I am with the loader swf.

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, reportKeyDown);
```

Solution-Edit: 
The problem is that the loaded SWFs are using the "stage" property, and when they're loaded into another SWF the stage isn't theirs to own. That's what's causing the errors :) @BotMaster

Solution-Solution Edit:
You can still look for keyboard inputs (like I was doing) in a nested SWF, if you're using the

```
Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE
```

Like this, for instance :)

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);
function onAdded(e:Event):void{
    trace("added");
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, reportKeyDown); 
}
```

@null

Comment: Show the code from your BallGame.fla frame 1.

Comment: There's quite a lot of it, and I think it's hard to understand without seeing the objects that it's interacting with. Everything takes place in frame 1, I'm just using Greensock tweens to move things around with code ^^

Comment: Literally thousands of times this comes back and thousands of posts are showing and explaining why: Referencing "stage" in the loaded swf before it is added to a display list.

Comment: @BotMaster Great to hear that it seems there is a solution. I don't quite understand what you're telling me though. Care to explain what I'm doing wrong, please :)?

Comment: there can be only one stage, your main app owns it but your loaded swfs don't. Yet they still use "stage" as if they own it but they don't. That means in those swfs 'stage' does not exist and returns null and produce error. As soon as you add one loaded swf to a display list (stage.addChild(movie);) it can then use the stage but it's too late since you already have errors. When you run a swf by itself it owns the stage so you can't get error but if you load that swf inside another it doesn't own the stage anymore.

Comment: Ah, alright! :) Makes sense. Just have to add a keyboard event without using stage then, hmm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stage` only becomes available (it's not `null`) when the `DisplayObject` is added to the display list.

The only exception to that rule is the main file or the first file that is opened in the flash player.
That's why each of your games plays fine individually.

You should only use `stage` property if it is available. To do this, listen for the `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` event. This will be dispatched when something is added to the stage. In the handler function, you can safely use `stage`.

You still should add the listener to the `stage` but only if it is available to you.

---

Please read the documentation about addChild(). You should basically **never** add anything to `stage`. In general, take a look at the basics of the display list and how it works.

Comment: The listeners from the previously loaded SWFs are still active, even after I've removed the visuals with  stage.removeChildren(1); 
Got an idea of how I can get rid of that, sorry to be such a bother :)

Comment: @user3307017 that sounds like an interesting new question. =)

Comment: I suppose. I gave up :)